# Santa's Surprise Spell

Tags: clash-of-clans

In friendly challenge I could see that after I use the *Santa's Surprise* spell on something, after the damage is done to the buildings, a couple of *Presents* appear on that base. What are the *Presents* for? Do they do something during attack or after the attack? I couldn't figure it out as I am not attacked with that spell yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you have been attacked, the presents are just like the tombstones from fallen attacker troops. When you click on a present or tombstone, they are all "collected", and you get 5000 elixir for each present.

Comment: Not the tombstones. The tombstones give 50 elixir each, the dark tombstones 1 dark elixir each.

Comment: The Tombstones give you **2**0 Elixir each. @PythonMaster

Answer (score 1):

Sad to say, the presents do not stay in friendly challenges. Supercell saw to it that we can't stack up elixer for fellow clan mates. Would have been a nice oversight on their part. No surprise. It's almost better that if we ever figure out a good strategy or troop combo to keep it to ourselves ans not share it with anyone except trusted friends & clan mates who will not pass on the info to anyone. Seems like any time we do, Supercell hears of it and nerfs it. Look at each strategy, glitch, edge, even war weight. Bland is the new flavour now. Seems like all the hard work anyone puts into discovering something new is destroyed by some whiner crying that his half maxed th7 got destroyed by a th9 attack. And yes, lv4 valks are OP for a th8 base AS THEY SHOULD BE, but so are level 6 archers. Same with easy ways to acquire loot. Farming is killed off. Why should SC be any different to allow gifts to remain in friendly challenges. At least this Christmas theme was more fun and SC did give us a few things.